# How to tag additional parameter onto constructor and inject dependencies using Unity?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have a host service with 2 service interface dependencies, but I would like to tag a 3rd string parameter in the constructor.  Currently the first 2 are already registered so are supplied correctly when resolving.

Depending on whether my service boots-up from command line or command host (using TopShelf), I want to be able to inject a 3rd value from the command line, either supply empty if not supplied or call the constructor with just the 2 interface dependencies.

I've seen the ParameterOverride() class but I don't want to have re-define the first 2 parameters again if these are already registered. I'm also not sure how Unity can pick either the greedy constructor or the slim one depending if the parameter exists.

e.g.

```
  public HostService(ISchedulerService schedulerService,
                     IConfigService configService,
                     string commandLineValue)
        { }
```

How do I get Unity to inject the services as normal but also supply the 3rd value?

```
container.RegisterType<IHostService, HostService>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507497(v=pandp.30).aspx), there is a solution for when you need to add a parameter to a constructor:

```
container.RegisterType<HostService>(new InjectionConstructor(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3))
```

I would also investigate whether this works:

1. Add another constructor without the `commandLineValue` parameter (constructor overloading) or:
2. Set the `commandLineValue` parameter with a default value

as in:

```
public HostService(ISchedulerService schedulerService, IConfigService configService, string commandLineValue = string.Empty)
{}
```

so there is no need to provide the third parameter.